# Integrate Google Drive with my CRM to allow creation and collaboration on files

Tags: php, crm, google-drive-api

Here is the deal - our internal CRM is used for managing the huge amount of estimate requests we receive each day. The software is built with php / codeigniter / mySql. It allows our sales team to store a lot of information regarding the lead and when the time is right, generate estimates and even contracts. 
Let’s focus on the contract.
When the user hits the "Create contract" button, the software gathers all the information like Client name, address, social security number and stuff like that. Using this information and a couple of On/off options it generates the contract dynamically. Of course it always needs some editing, that’s where my problem starts.

The user has to edit the document in a TinyMCE box - sort of a WYSIWYG editor. This editor sucks for complex editing.

We use Google apps for business, so here is what I would like to do: When the user hits the Create Contract button, the software has to gather the dynamic information and create a file on Google Drive with our contract layout and information. Then the user is free to edit the file using the Google Drive interface which is great.

Does anybody know a approach for this?

Best regards and sorry for the bad English.